# making block level elements clickable links

Tags: html, css

I have the following design problem. I have a list of items and I want to make the whole of each of the first li to be a clickable link. I have tried adding a link in each li, making it a block level element and positioning it absolute, but that doesn't work because the parent and all li's are floated left for layout purposes. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
<ul style='float:left;width:x>

   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Title</li>
         <li>Description</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Title</li>
         <li>Description</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li>
      <ul>
         <li>Title</li>
         <li>Description</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I recommend this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/

Answer (score 0):

If the parent `li` has `position: relative`, you can position things absolutely inside it without messing with the way the parent floats around.

Another, somewhat inelegant solution would be to add an `onclick` event to each of the parent `li`s, and use JavaScript to change the URL. Also, add `cursor: pointer` to your CSS to make it look like a link. But as I said, this is not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about jQuery as an option? Its probably not the best solution but it would work. so i would rig something up like this:

```
$("ul li:first-child").bind('click',function(){
    // click event here.
    alert("Boom!");
    $(this).find("li a").trigger('click');
});
```

and i would have your code look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">title</a></li>
        <li>description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">title</a></li>
        <li>description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">title</a></li>
        <li>description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">title</a></li>
        <li>description</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the links in the li and use `display:block`. Don't absolutely position them.